# Delphi update a parent form control from a child form

Tags: delphi

From a form, I create and show a second form.  From the second form I want to update a control on the first form.    But I get access violations.  I can get it to work with the form in the autocreate, but not when I create the form with the create method I get violations.

Below is an example.  If I run it as it is with form 11 in autocreate it works (I update a button caption in the first form).  But, if in unit 10, if I comment out form11.show;, and I uncomment the create and the show and then take Form11 out of autocreate, I get an access violation.

Question - How can I update the parent form from the showed form when I create the form with a create method.

Unit10

```
unit Unit10;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  TForm10 = class(TForm)
     Button1: TButton;
     procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
private
{ Private declarations }
public
{ Public declarations }
end;
var
  Form10: TForm10;
implementation
uses Unit11;
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm10.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fForm     : TForm11;
Begin
//        fForm := Form11.Create(Self);  //This and next line give me access violation
//        fForm.Show;           //   with form11 out of autocreate
   form11.show;            //This works with form11 in the autocreate.
end;
end.
```

Unit11

```
unit Unit11;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;
type
  TForm11 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;
var
  Form11: TForm11;
implementation
uses unit10;
{$R *.dfm}
procedure TForm11.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
form10.button1.caption := 'Changed';
end;
end.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
fForm := Form11.Create(Self)
```

It should be like this:

```
fForm := TForm11.Create(Self)
```

That is, `TForm11`, not `Form11`. To create an object, you have to call the constructor via the class.

Answer (score 2):

I've always just had my forms auto-creating and can't think of a reason to not do so, but here's the likely cause of your problem:
The `Create` method needs to be called on a class, not on a variable.

This line would probably work to create a new instance of TForm11:

```
    fForm := TForm11.Create(Self);
```

Comment: In general, you should NOT auto-create any Forms other than the MainForm.  Dynamically create your Forms on an as-needed basis instead. It speeds up your app's startup, and it is nicer to memory usage.

Comment: There are probably four dozen reasons not to auto-create forms. Memory use, slow startup, and wasted CPU cycles are the three that come to mind immediately. The first thing I've always done on a new Delphi install is go to Tools->Options->VCL Designer (Form Designer in newer versions) and uncheck "Auto-create forms and data modules".